# Meteor can't read entire resource file while building

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a Meteor app that's suddenly not building.

Upon running 'meteor run'

I now get the following log

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0_2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: couldn't read entire resource
    at Object.files.readBufferWithLengthAndOffset (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1868:13)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\unibuild.js:122:26
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0_2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at Function.fromJSON (C:\tools\isobuild\unibuild.js:119:7)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:921:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0_2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at Isopack._loadUnibuildsFromPath (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:908:7)
    at Isopack.initFromPath (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:828:17)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:280:23
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at Profile.time (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:266:24)
    at Function.time (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:305:10)
    at IsopackCache._ensurePackageLoaded (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:256:15)
    at ensureLoaded (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:207:12)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:299:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0_2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at IsopackCache._ensurePackageLoaded (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:298:9)
    at ensureLoaded (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:207:12)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:299:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0_2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at IsopackCache._ensurePackageLoaded (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:298:9)
    at ensureLoaded (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:207:12)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:299:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0_2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at IsopackCache._ensurePackageLoaded (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:298:9)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:75:14
    at C:\tools\packaging\package-map.js:57:7
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0_2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at exports.PackageMap.eachPackage (C:\tools\packaging\package-map.js:49:7)
    at IsopackCache.buildLocalPackages (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:74:24)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:869:25
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at ProjectContext._buildLocalPackages (C:\tools\project-context.js:868:18)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:300:9
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at ProjectContext._completeStagesThrough (C:\tools\project-context.js:290:18)
    at Profile.run (C:\tools\project-context.js:282:12)
    at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)
    at ProjectContext.prepareProjectForBuild (C:\tools\project-context.js:281:13)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:544:29
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:283:5)
    at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:543:31)
    at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:610:35)
    at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:908:28)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:398:12
```

I couldn't find much about this online. I restarted my computer a few times, ran

```
meteor reset
```

and even deleted my project and recloned to a new copy of it to account for any local changes. Does anybody have any idea of what's going on here? I'm running Win 10 btw. The issue seems local to my computer, as it's working on others. I think re-installing Meteor/Node could fix the issue, but I'd rather understand what exactly caused it.

Comment: Is your disk full? Low on memory? Disk fragmented? On Linux or Mac you can run out of inodes (and yet the disk isn't full) - not sure if that applies here

Comment: Neither of those, not sure what caused it, but see solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renistalling Meteor and Node alone didn't do the trick. Uninstalling Meteor didn't remove the .meteor folder. Completely removing that folder and then reinstalling made everything work again.

Not sure what exactly cause the issue in the first place though, but a fresh restart did it.

Comment: At least you fixed it :)

Comment: Just hope it doesn't come back